# How the hibernate fetch the peristent object from cache(1/2)

Tags: hibernate

How the hibernate API fetch the persistent object from cache second time (1st level and 2 nd Level).

I know, first request fetched from database and give the persistent object and also put into 1st level cache( also 2nd level cache if enabled).

When I query the second time how it will fetch from cache? How `load()` and `get()` will fetch?

Also, what is the role of `equals()`, `hashcode()` in the persistent pojo? Based on this `equals()` it will fetch the persistent object from cache?

If `equals()` fails (implemented proper way) what will happen, means each and every time it will hit the database?

Answer (score 0):

When your `Entity` becomes managed within the current session, is placed within the `PersistenceContext`.

Every `load` or `get` operation will query the that context, if the `Entity` is present there, it return it's instance, otherwise, it will hit the database. It happens also for lazy loading.

[Blog article with examples about this, used as reference](http://apmblog.compuware.com/2009/02/16/understanding-caching-in-hibernate-part-one-the-session-cache)

---

Implementing the `equals()` and `hashcode()` it's required when

> intend to put instances of persistent classes in a Set (the recommended way to represent many-valued associations) *and*
>   intend to use reattachment of detached instances

The first level cache doesn't use the `equals()` method to manage it's context. The `StatefulPersistenceContext` uses the `EntityKey`.

```
@Override
public boolean containsEntity(EntityKey key) {
    return entitiesByKey.containsKey( key );
}
```

From the `DefaultLoadEventListener` class

```
    protected Object loadFromSessionCache(
        final LoadEvent event,
        final EntityKey keyToLoad,
        final LoadEventListener.LoadType options) throws HibernateException {

    SessionImplementor session = event.getSession();
    Object old = session.getEntityUsingInterceptor( keyToLoad );

    if ( old != null ) {
        // this object was already loaded
        EntityEntry oldEntry = session.getPersistenceContext().getEntry( old );
        if ( options.isCheckDeleted() ) {
            Status status = oldEntry.getStatus();
            if ( status == Status.DELETED || status == Status.GONE ) {
                return REMOVED_ENTITY_MARKER;
            }
        }
        if ( options.isAllowNulls() ) {
            final EntityPersister persister = event.getSession()
                    .getFactory()
                    .getEntityPersister( keyToLoad.getEntityName() );
            if ( !persister.isInstance( old ) ) {
                return INCONSISTENT_RTN_CLASS_MARKER;
            }
        }
        upgradeLock( old, oldEntry, event.getLockOptions(), event.getSession() );
    }

    return old;
}
```

So no, `equals()` is not required when caching.

[Article about equals() and hashcode()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/persistent-classes-equalshashcode.html)

[Another article, deep thoughts and examples](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-equals-and-hashcode/)